Incompatible version of libocijdbc
I am using mybatis-config.xml to connect Oracle jdbc Driver and can ran correctly by using following connection.

<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@service_name/>

But when I use like that

<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:oci:@service_name/>

the following error is occured.

[Thu Aug 01 09:58:58.309 2024] 10:00:03.275 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection
[Thu Aug 01 09:58:58.709 2024] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:193000, Jdbc-OCI:1918000
[Thu Aug 01 09:58:58.711 2024]    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:4298)

How can I resolve the version conflict between jdbc and oci?
Please suggest my any possible way to connect to oracle database through service_name.

I'm guessing that your Oracle Instant Client installation is not compatible with your Oracle database. maybe this will help?

A DEBUG level log message is rarely an error. What are the consecuenques? What fails?

Yes. I adjusted oci and jdbc version and it worked.

It looks like you are using JDBC driver 19.3 while the native OCI lib version is 19.18. You can resolve the error by upgrading your JDBC driver to 19.18 release.

Thank you for your answer. I upgraded JDBC driver and it worked...
